# setError icon overlapping the outline of TextInputLayout (TextInputEditText)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

So I've been having this problem for a while now and can't figure out how to fix it. The same thing was happening with ExposedDropdownMenu and the arrow icon on the end, but I gave up eventually.

I've tried putting custom icons/backgrounds with endIconDrawable but it didn't help. It's almost like there is a "reserved" view for the icon at the end and that view is overlapping the stroke/outline of the TextInputEditText. I've googled a lot, but apparently no one else had this problem so I'd really appreciate any help or ideas!

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                            android:id="@+id/inputAddTransactionDescription"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerAddTransactionType">

                                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                                    android:id="@+id/inputAddTransactionDescription1"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:inputType="text"
                                    android:textColor="@color/main_text"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                                    android:hint="Description*" />
                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFvG5.png